# Foam board off gassing and vapor trapping

Tags: heating

[image: In ceiling radiant heating system]

Will be using this in ceiling radiant system in my home. Will the off gassing from the foam board be trapped by the drywall from coming into my home?  What can I do to stop it from coming into my home?  It will also be in the ceiling of my basement.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try Googling "polyisocyanurate out gassing", or something similar?

Comment: Yes, it does off gas. Question is, how to contain it and keep it out of the house.

Comment: The ceiling of the living space would be easy exhaust the attic space with a powered vent   Adding to the ceiling of the basement, would be a bigger problem as the off gas has to go somewhere and there are only living spaces. Put it and take a weeks vacation to miss the majority.